Jenkins Kubernetes Pipeline Error: Node is not a Kubernetes Node
Issue Details:
The issue is that the Nginx server cannot be started, and it's unclear what prevents the service from starting. Do I need to configure pods in the Jenkins Kubernetes configuration? Can somebody help me solve this issue?
Description
I have set up Jenkins and Kubernetes on my localhost environment. For Jenkins, I have deployed a Jenkins Docker container, and for Kubernetes, I'm using Minikube (also running as a Docker container) on the host system. Additionally, I've installed kubectl on the host.
Installed Jenkins Plugins:
I have installed two Jenkins plugins:

Kubernetes
Docker (not utilized in this setup)

Kubernetes Cloud Configuration:
I configured a Kubernetes cloud named "my-k8s" in Jenkins. For configuration, I utilized a secret file. The secret file content is obtained from ~$ cat .kube/config and updated the certificate with actual data.
Connection Testing:
When testing the connection in http://192.168.1.41:8080/manage/cloud/my-k8s/configure, it shows that it's 'Connected to Kubernetes v1.28.3'.
Jenkins Pipeline Syntax:
Below is my Jenkins pipeline syntax:
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Deploy Nginx to Kubernetes') {
            steps {
                container('Kubernetes') {
                    // Configure Kubernetes server details
                    // credentialsId 'kubernetes-credentials' // Replace with your credential ID // I don't know what credentialsId
                    serverName 'https://192.168.49.2:8443' // Kubernetes API server URL(~$ cat .kube/conf )
                    namespace 'default' // Replace with your desired namespace

                    // Define Nginx deployment YAML
                    script {
                        def deploymentYaml = """
                        apiVersion: apps/v1
                        kind: Deployment
                        metadata:
                          name: nginx-deployment
                          labels:
                            app: nginx
                        spec:
                          replicas: 1
                          selector:
                            matchLabels:
                              app: nginx
                          template:
                            metadata:
                              labels:
                                app: nginx
                            spec:
                              containers:
                              - name: nginx
                                image: nginx:latest
                                ports:
                                - containerPort: 80
                        """
                        writeFile file: 'nginx-deployment.yaml', text: deploymentYaml
                    }

                    // Deploy Nginx using Kubernetes plugin
                    kubernetesApply file: 'nginx-deployment.yaml'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Issue:
When running this pipeline, the Jenkins log shows:
Started by user admin
Replayed #1
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/kube-nginx-project
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy Nginx to Kubernetes)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Node is not a Kubernetes node: 
Finished: FAILURE


You may want to consider checking the URL configuration within your pipeline script and Kubernetes API server. You can verify as well if the port used is correct and open.
Including here a sample steps-by-steps by adkarigar where the error you encountered was produced. You can refer to this documentation for cross matching with your syntax.
